# How to properly verify MyMonero?

Tags: mymonero

How do we ensure that the MyMonero executable is legit? The sha hashes are published on Github, but where is the maintainer's public key to check that he signed the executable or zip file? That's the only sure shot of confirming that the file is not tampered with.

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, the releases up until now haven't been signed.

What is possible at the moment is you could clone the existing GitHub repository at https://github.com/mymonero/mymonero-app-js and build the desktop app from source. We realise this is a bit cumbersome.

That said, there will be a new version released soon with GPG-signed hashes, and all future versions will be signed in the same fashion.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Karl - any progress on GPG verification for the app?

Comment: Also see https://github.com/mymonero/mymonero-app-js/issues/297